# Ubuntu 18.04 repeated "Anthentification required by Wireless network"?

Tags: 18.04, wireless

So I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 desktop alongside Windows 10. 
But despite the fact that the password I typed is correct, I still get prompted by this message.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05c8:03ab Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

eno1      no wireless extensions.

$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723de
    Kernel modules: rtl8723de
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: What is the kernel version?

Comment: Did you set the ant_sel=2 parameter?

Answer (score -1):

`sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf`

Copy and past this line and save and exit:

`options rtl8723de fwlps=0`

Reboot.

This should prevent the WiFi card from automatically sleeping and halting connection.

Comment: What makes you think that this is a random solution ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "specificity" in your command